# ColdFusion 10 root folder

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I am new to ColdFusion 10 and I want to run it on localhost, so I download it and install it and done successfully. Now I want to create file and want to check by running it.
For example my file name is test.cfm so how to run it on localhost and in which folder i should save this file. I have Installed CF 10 in D directory.

```
D directory

   |__ ColdFusion10
```

Kindly someone tell me how to do it. I dont find any solution, I find solution that use CF Builder but I dont want to install builder.
Please guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your answer

Here is complete structure that will help you to understand

```
    D directory
       |__ ColdFusion10
             |__cfusion
                   |__wwwroot
                      |__ test.cfm
```

basically you will put your files in `wwwroot` folder.
hope you will now understand